# Capistrano/Sidekiq task not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, sidekiq, capistrano3

I am using rails 4.0 and ruby 2.3.

I am using following gems for capscript.

```
capistrano (3.4.0)
capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
capistrano-rails (1.1.5)
```

I am using capistrano/sidekiq module for running sidekiq related tasks.

When I am running

```
 cap staging sidekiq:start
```

I get the following error:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as      deploy@10.50.11.190: sidekiq exit status: 1
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: sidekiq exit status: 1
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: Nothing written
```

Below is the command which failed on running the above task.

```
cd /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/current && /usr/bin/env sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile     /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid -- environment staging --logfile /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/log/sidekiq.log --config /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/config/sidekiq.yml --daemon
```

I tried running the above command directly on the staging server with a small change and it worked. I ran the following command.

```
 cd /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/current/server && /usr/bin/env sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile  /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment staging --logfile /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/log/sidekiq.log --config /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/shared/server/config/sidekiq.yml --daemon
```

I changed the rails path from

```
 /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/current --> /opt/optimus_apps/merchant_tracking/current/server
```

The problem is my rails app lies inside current/server folder.

So my question is how can I make sidekiq task to pick current/server folder rather than the current folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following the "convention over configuration" principle, it would be better to just have the rails app in `.../current` rather than `.../current/server`. Is this a practical solution?

Comment: I am using rails for apis and ember for frontend. So instead of separate repo I created one repo with a server folder for rails app and a client folder for ember app.

Comment: A *possible* alternative would be to edit the `RAILS_ROOT` variable (in `config/environments/production`). But I'm not sure what the full consequences of such a change would be, without trying for myself.